# Not able to set Assignee for the JIRA Bug using Jira client rcarz / jira-client

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

JIRA bug is getting created successfully but it is not getting assigned, Assignee remains as "UNASSIGNED".

I am passing the below details:-

```
issue.field(Field.SUMMARY, summary);
issue.field(Field.DESCRIPTION, description);
issue.field(Field.ASSIGNEE, "Name of the assignee");
issue.execute();
```

The Summary and Descriptions are getting populated correctly, in place of the name of the assignee I have also tried to pass the ID of the user but even that does not work.

Client being used: https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client

Answer (score 0):

After the latest GDPR regulations in APIs , users wont be able to add assignee solely based on name, ID will be the way to assign issues.

There are other methods where one can fetch all assignee list and then sort out the assignee one wants and use it. But i am not sure about it.